# What is proper notation for common (decimal) logarithm?

Tags: notation, logarithms, convention

The calculators usually use  $\log x$, while articles on wikipedia and other websites often use $\log_{10} x$, finally the ISO-80000-2:2009 uses $\lg x$.

Which one of these is correct? Or at least expected? If there isn't one, is any considered *incorrect* or *discouraged*?

Is the convention varied by regions perhaps?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499094/natural-logarithm-notation and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293783/when-log-is-written-without-a-base-is-the-equation-normally-referring-to-log-ba and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552038/are-base-ten-logarithms-relics and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071963/should-the-notation-log-x-mean-the-decimal-logarithm and probably many, many more.

Comment: See [Common logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_logarithm) as well as [Logarithm: Particular bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Particular_bases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not $\log(x)$. That is reserved for natural log. I would say use $\log_{10}(x)$.

Edit: This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/293785/40119) is more complete and correct. In computer science $\log(x)$ often means $\log_2(x)$. (Thanks also to @Qudit for mentioning this.)

Comment: Isn't $\mathrm{ln}$ for natural $\log$?

Comment: I thought that $\log(x)$ is too ambiguous. But saw it few times used with no explanation.

Comment: @user1561358 $\log x$ is commonly used for $\ln x$ in analysis.  In theoretical computer science, $\log x$ usually means $\log_2 x$.