# Why is this a description $\log_{10}$ if the intervals between $10, 100, 1000$ are not equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

In one [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552038/are-base-ten-logarithms-relics/552105#552105) in regards to the current value of $\log_{10}$ the following was mentioned:

> For these purposes, $10$ does have **at least one useful feature**
> beyond being the base of our number system: $\log_{10} 2 = 0.301 ≈
> > 0.3$. This is a very common approximation that $3$ dB corresponds to a doubling or halving of the quantity of interest. We could get similar
> simplicity by using $\log_{2}$, but $\log_2 10 = 3.321…$ which is not
> nearly as convenient for estimation in decimal numbers.

If I understand this correctly 1dB is $\frac{1}{10}= 0.1$ and since $\log_{10} 2 ≈ 0.3$ we consider the noise has been doubled for $3$dB.
To conclude that we must work on a logarithmic scale with base $10$.

But doesn't that imply that the distance between $10$ and $100$ must be equal to the distance between $1$ and $10$? In the case of dB if we move at $\frac{1}{10}$ we have a distance of $10\frac{1}{10}$ from $1$ to $10$ but $1000\frac{1}{10}$ from $10$ to $100$. Doesn't this break the requirement that it is a $\log_{10}$ scale? Or have I misunderstood the point?

Comment: The [decibel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) is not a measure on a linear scale. Hence you can't just say that you "move at $\frac1{10}$, whatever it may mean. Instead, you compute the logarithm of the ratio of the two values, i.e. you are computing the difference of the logarithms, i.e. you "move linearly" on a **log scale**.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: So for the the ratio of the values represents the $log_{10}$ and the value of the log the intensity? So the $1/10$ is not the diff per unit on the scale as I thought? To create such a system is there some requirement for the original values? Or we could create such a scale with arbitrary decimal values?